# JDA how to get a message by ID

Tags: java, discord-jda

Is there a way to get a message by only having his ID and his `TextChannel` ID ?

I found this :

```java
Message message = TextChannel.getHistory().getMessageById(String id);
```

But it just throw an error : `net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ErrorResponseException: 10008: Unknown Message`

Comment: `getHistory` is not a static method and `getMessageById` cannot throw that exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MessageChannel#retrieveMessageById(id)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#retrieveMessageById(java.lang.String)):

```java
channel.retrieveMessageById(id).queue((message) -> {
    // use the message here, its an async callback
    message.addReaction(reaction).queue();
    message.editMessage("bleh").queue();
    System.out.println("Message Content: " + message.getContentDisplay());
}, new ErrorHandler().handle(ErrorResponse.UNKNOWN_MESSAGE, (e) -> {
    // this means the message doesn't exist
    channel.sendMessage("That message doesn't exist!").queue();
}));
```

Also worth looking at:

- [editMessageById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#editMessageById(java.lang.String,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message))
- [deleteMessageById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#deleteMessageById(java.lang.String))
- [getIterableHistory](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#getIterableHistory())
- [addReactionById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#addReactionById(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Comment: Oh thanks you very much ! I have a question, what is the difference between a TextChannel and a MessageChannel though ?

Comment: A MessageChannel can be a PrivateChannel or a TextChannel, a TextChannel is a MessageChannel and a GuildChannel. TextChannel != PrivateChannel

Comment: How do I know the id of the message when the message will be sent by the bot itself?